# Is the closed ball $\overline{\textrm{B}}_1(0,1)$ the closure of the open ball $\textrm{B}_1(0,1)$ in $(C[a,b],\|\cdot\|_p)$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

*Notation*: Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ with $a<b$, and let $V$ be the set of all continuous functions $f : [a,b]\to\mathbb R$.

- For $p \in [1,\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$, and $f \in V$, let
  $$\|f\|_p := \begin{cases} 
  \bigg( \displaystyle \int_a^b |f(x)|^pdx \bigg)^{1/p} & \textrm{if } p \in [1,\infty), \\
  \max\{|f(x)| : x \in [a,b]\} & \textrm{if } p = \infty.
  \end{cases}$$
- For $p \in [1,\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$, $f_0 \in V$, and $\varepsilon>0$, let $$\textrm{B}_p(f_0,\varepsilon) := \{f \in V : \|f-f_0\|_p < \varepsilon\}, \\ \overline{\textrm{B}}_p(f_0,\varepsilon) := \{f \in V : \|f-f_0\|_p \leq \varepsilon\}.$$

---

Now, for every $p \in [1,\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$, I claim that the closure of $A:=\textrm{B}_1(0,1)$ in $(V,\|\cdot\|_p)$ is $B:=\overline{\textrm{B}}_1(0,1)$.

> *My attempt:* I already know that the identity $$\operatorname{id}_V : (V,\|\cdot\|_p) \to (V,\|\cdot\|_1)$$ is continuous, so, using the fact that if $\phi : X \to Y$ is continuous, then $\phi(\overline{U}) \subseteq \overline{\phi(U)}$ for any $U \subseteq X$, we can conclude that the closure of $A$ in $(V,\|\cdot\|_p)$ is contained in the closure of $A$ in $(V,\|\cdot\|_1)$, which is $B$.

What about the other inclusion? Is that true? Or it is only true for some values of $p$, like $p=1$? Also, using the continuity of the same identity map, I find out $A$ is open in $(V,\|\cdot\|_p)$, and $B$ is closed in $(V,\|\cdot\|_p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other inclusion is true. It is sufficient to show that any $f\in V$ with $\|f\|_1=1$ is contained in $\overline{B_1(0,1)}^{\|\cdot\|_p}$.

Fix $f\in V$ with $\|f\|_1=1$ and define $f_n=(1-1/n)f$, for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Surely, $$\|f_n\|_1= 1-1/n<1,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,$$ so the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is contained in $B_1(0,1)$. Moreover,
$$
\|f-f_n\|_p = \frac{\|f\|_p}{n} \to 0,
$$
so, $f\in \overline{B_1(0,1)}^{\|\cdot\|_p}$.